# How to find out current working directory of a child process?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, process

I am running a main script that generates 40 directories to run 40 child processes in parallel. One of the child processes is running forever and I want to know which directory is it in. I have tried the following:

```
$ pwdx <PID>

$ lsof -p <PID> | grep cwd
```

But I can only get the current working directory of the main script.

So how can I find out the current working directory of a child process given its PID?

Comment: Add some code to log which child process runs in which folder.

Comment: Please carefully proofread your question. It doesn't make sense at the moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `readlink /proc/<PID>/cwd`. If this does not show the required information, I would conclude that your platform does not provide it, but since you have Linux, it should work.

BTW, this approach does not require, that the process being looked up is a **child** process of yours.

Comment: It still shows the directory of the main script for me.

Comment: It shows the directory of that process where you are passing the PID. This means that you are using a wrong PID. You have to provide the PID of **that** process you want to know the working directory, as I explained.

Comment: Of course I am providing the PID of that child process.

Comment: Then you should see the working directory of the child process. Perhaps the child process has not issued yet a cd command?

Comment: You can easily test, whether your Linux is doing it in the expected way, by running i.e. `bash -c '(cd /tmp; sleep 400)& echo $!; wait'`. This will print the PID of the child process to stdout, and in a different terminal you then use the `readlink` command on that PID to verify that the working directory is indeed `/tmp`.